# No counter section defined

Tags: macros

What might be wrong when one gets the error

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'section' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.229 \newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]
```

What does it mean to have `No counter 'section' defined.` ?

I am using

```
%% piston.sty
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This is the document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{piston}

\begin{document}

Some Text Here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without `\documentclass`?

Comment: Yet another question without compilable code. We've told you many times that you need to embed code fragments into small documents that can reproduce the error.

Comment: May I know is it really needs the tags `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `Off` for this code?

Comment: @MadyYuvi The OP likes underscores so much they use `\ExplSyntaxOn` to allow them, despite being told this is a bad idea.

Comment: You really need to post more reasonable questions with code that reproduces the problem. Posting several questions a day that get closed as unclear just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: This is a style file I am using and just include it in my document.

Comment: @AlanMunn If I am allowed it is not a bad idea.  The implementation might be what's bad.

Comment: There you are. Now the question is complete (I've voted to reopen.) BTW: the problem is simply that the `letter` class does not define `\section` and the corresponding counter. If you had posted the complete code from the very beginning...

Comment: @Veak --- You are _allowed_ to do something like `\def\a{\a}\a`. I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: @campa Do you want to answer? I thought this must be a duplicate, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: There is no need for the `\ExplSyntaxOn`. `\newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]` works also without it (unless you use a package like underscore which makes the underscore active and gives it a fragile definition, but then using expl3 syntax for the theorem definition only wouldn't help.)

Comment: @cfr Your wish is my command `:-)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I incorporated your comment in my answer, I hope it's OK.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Have always been told that I need \`ExplSyntaxOn` whenever I use `_`.

Comment: If you want to use `_` in command names starting with a backslash, but here you have an environment and so internally a csname. Everything that works in `\csname ...\endcsname` is allowed.

Comment: I would require it anyway, as I have other things defined in the actual style file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
\newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]
```

you define a theorem whose counter is reset at every increase of the `section` counter. However, sectioning commands and the corresponding counters are not defined in the LaTeX kernel but in class files. The `letter` class doesn't define `\section`, and you get the error.

Unrelated: As Ulrike points out in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697783/no-counter-section-defined#comment1733421_697783), in this case you can in fact use an underscore even without `\ExplSyntaxOn` (since environment names are put between `\csname...\endcsname`). However, this is a bit dangerous, because some package might define the underscore as active character.

Comment: So you sneek in `\csname`.  Such convenience is what makes the code much more difficult to follow.

Comment: @Veak I don't quite follow.

Comment: The inclusion of `\csname` for the environment name only.

Comment: @Veak given that environments do something, it is hardly surprising surely that at some point the environment name invokes a command name.

Comment: @Veak the latex manual and any latex tutorial will tell you that `\begin{foo}` invokes `\foo`.  `\csname` is the tex primitive that makes that possible.